# How to add an blocks in Android

Tags: android, mysql, android-layout, android-studio

I want to create an landing view for my application a user log in they need to land on this activity page (Image 1) if they click on any of the icon they will be take to the activity page of that activity. I want it needed to be change when user turn their screen to vertical or horizontal. But I don't know where to start.

Below I have added two images to show what I want to implement in my application. This is for my college project. In the landing view it have alert box and another box text from MySQL database but I am stuck in all points.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a dashboard activity/ fragment...

something like this.
 the rotation of the screen is not a big problem, in fact, with the sdk you can design your activities and define behaviours of completely other layouts depending on the screen size, orienttation etc...

The work to do is not complicated but you need to do  couple of stuff  first, (define some layouts, classese etc,)

my recomendation is to take a look at this tutorial, and develope your app by following this [steps](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/12/android-dashboard-design-tutorial/)

[image]

Comment: Xoce ... It was an user dashboard when they log in they will be taken to this activity  screen. If they click on any of they we need them to take to that activity screen example if they click on profile they will be take to profile activity and their profile will be show there..

Comment: Xoce can you to tell me how to do it.. I have search in google for an answer but didn't find and answer for it.. Please help me

Comment: I put the link to the tutorial in the answer...

Comment: Thanks I will check it now .. thanks for the support If facing problems I will update it here.. Thank you..

Answer (score -1):

**1 -**

you can do it by set ImageButton in your main layout when click in any image will open new layout

show this link is simple code but he use button you can make some code and use ImageButton not Button only convert type name from button to ImageButton 
this is link= : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10936133/4967569

**2 -** 
**screen to vertical or horizonta**

i think you need use any size by Formula "dp"

**3 -**

sorry i cant help you in Database  I have No experience

Comment: This question was closed